# C++ Static Library in C Main Project

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

My VS2010 project has 2 Static Libraries in C. I want to add another one, but in C++. My main project is already in C, so my objective is to change it the minimum possible. Is it possible to add another static library in C++? How?
I already link the projects and only include the header in "main.cpp". But I get this error:

```
"1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosf' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2059: syntax error : ';' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'asinf' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2059: syntax error : ';' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atanf' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2059: syntax error : ';' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atan2f' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
```

The solutions that I already see, tell me to compile the main project in C++, which I can't do.

Comment: Give this a read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: Thanks I will read carefully

Answer (score 1):

If you can't compile the MainProject in C++ you could write a wrapper for your C++ Library to handle the functionality you need.

Basically build another library which links in the C++ library. It shall provide the functions as `extern "C"` and you can call them from your C application.

Check this link for more Information: http://www.teddy.ch/c++_library_in_c/

Comment: Can I create a exe. with the C++ library and execute inside of main project instead?

Comment: Could be done aswell, but isn't the nicest way. You would have to build all functions you will use like a command line app and interpret the results from within your c application. Believe me, would be a lot more work and complexicity. The Link provided by Mihai Todor is explaining the same as my answer. And i would definitly go this way, compile as static librarys with `extern "C"` and use it directly.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider that way. This library only converts a string of words to words+phonemes. Because of that "simple" implementation, I have considered to execute the library inside of main project.